Enter India using Indian Visa and Exit with OCI - Query
I have travelled to India in End of Sept with 90 days max stay limit on my India visa.  I just got an advice from Indian Consulate Sydney that my OCI will be delivered to my Sydney Address in a week's time.
Currently I am planning to return in End of Dec but if I somehow can get my OCI shipped to India with a friend, Can I stay longer in India, let's say till End of Jan? Would I face any issue while exiting India? Would I have any issues while entering India again in the future?

No, you can't do that. Depending on the type of visa you entered India with, it may or may not be extendable. e-Visa's aren't extendable. And to be crystal clear, I'm advising against overstaying the allowed entry date on your visa and assuming that you can leave by just showing your OCI card.
You have two options, after you receive your OCI card in Sydney and then presumably have it couriered to you back in India.

Go to your nearest FRRO(Foreigners Registration Office) office and explain your situation, they can essentially do a change of status and will give you additional paperwork that you can present when at the Immigration counter when you leave.
The other option is for you to make a day trip to a bordering country like Nepal, Bhutan or Sri Lanka and then come back to India and be admitted with your OCI card. Once admitted with an OCI card, there are no limitations as to how long you can stay in India.

